# mail received/moved/deleted/created/sent event in Outlook vsto

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

What is the best way to detect if an email is received/moved/deleted/created/sent in Outlook?

I know of NewMail/NewMailEx on the Application and BeforeItemMove on a Folder.

NewMail/NewMailEx covers the mail received case but I need to handle all scenarios where something happens to a message.

BeforeItemMove is helpful but I need an application wide event, not a folder specific one. I could walk the folder tree and add event handlers for every folder but it doesn't seem right.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with drventure. I have used the actions in outlook within my own application to do events. I.e. on moving an email it comes up with a dialog, with sending it does something else.

Here is a link that got me started:

http://easyvsto.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/how-to-save-mail-content-when-a-mail-is-sent-from-outlook/

Further to the send action in the link above, there is a move action as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is such an event. What I've done in the past is monitor the app object for when the "active" folder changes. In that event, I connect up to whatever the active folder is and start monitoring IT for changes to it's contained email items, under the notion that for a user to do anything to the items in a folder, that have to first have navigated to that folder.

Comment: Do you think the assumption that for a user to do anything to the items in a folder, he has to first navigate to that folder is correct?

What if the user executes Outlook rules?
What if you make changes in the IMAP provider or in OWA and Outlook syncs the changes?